# SQL Query conversion nvarchar to data type int got error in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a question on this, I am not sure why I keep getting this error when I use this in stored procedure.

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value
>   '3,25,26,27,28,33,34' to data type int.

This is the query I used.

```
@idList nvarchar(max)

@idList='3,25,26,27,28,33,34'

update tSpecScaleValidation set LastTriggeredTime=getdate() where id in (@idList)
```

However, when I update without using stored proc, its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that variable `@idList='3,25,26,27,28,33,34'` is converted to int as whole. It is not converted as you think. You can not do it like this directly. Workaround is to use dynamic query:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(2000)
set @sql = 'udate tSpecScaleValidation set LastTriggeredTime=getdate() where id in (' + @idList + ')'
exec(@sql)
```

Beware of sql injection! Bad news that you can not parametrize this query, so be careful if you pass some data from client with variable `@idList`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `@idList` is `NVARCHAR` and the `WHERE` clause is evaluated as
`id = '3,25,26,27,28,33,34'`. And since `id` is `INT` and has [higher data type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) than `NVARCHAR`, `'3,25,26,27,28,33,34'` gets converted to `INT`, which then resulted to the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value
>   '3,25,26,27,28,33,34' to data type int.

An alternative is to use dynamic sql:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) 
set @sql= N'update tSpecScaleValidation set LastTriggeredTime = getdate() where id in (' + @idList + ');'

exec(@sql)
```

Or use a CSV splitter. Here is one taken from Aaron Bertrand's [article](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
```

And use it on your `UPDATE` statement

```
update tSpecScaleValidation 
    set LastTriggeredTime=getdate() 
where id in (
    select item
    from dbo.SplitStrings_XML(@idList, ',')
)
```